# Select rows grouped by keyword but weight each group instead of using COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I use MySQL database server and I have a table named `keywords` with the following structure:

```
kewyord_name | product_id
```

As well as a list of keywords. I can sort the `keywords` table based on the list with the following query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) 
FROM keywords 
WHERE keyword_name IN (comma separated list of keywords) 
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Is there a way to add weight to the keywords, i.e. for some of the keywords the COUNT(*) to be increased with more than one?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'weight' the keywords. Can you add some sample data/expected results? (Possibly an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) if you can).

Comment: Unless there is some simple rule (such as First letter =`a` the 1, `b` then 3 etc or no.of chars) then you would need a second table to define which words get higher weighting. If you do have a simple rule then use CASE IE  - SUM( CASE keyword_name WHEN 'FU' THEN 1 WHEN 'BAR' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END).

Comment: @McAdam331 Now all keywords a equal. What I mean is if there is a way to make some keywords to worth more that others.

Comment: @Giles I have a list of the keywords which are more special. There is not a lexical rule that can roll them out.

Comment: @Nikola Obreshkov- then you can put that list into a table (with a weight column if necessary) and JOIN to it to determine which keywords get a higher weight and use SUM() instead of count (with a CASE or IF() if necessary). If the list is short enough then the SUM(CASE... I showed above would be sufficient.

Comment: Added another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the COUNT(*) function you'll only be able to increment by one with each row. If you want keywords to be treated differently, you could use the SUM() function with a case block.

For example, let's say you have keywords `This`, `that`, `these`. If you want keyword `this` and `that` to have a weight of 3, `these` a weight of 2, and anything else a weight of 1, you can do this:

```
SELECT keyword_name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN keyword_name IN ('this', 'that') THEN 3
      WHEN keyword_name IN ('these') THEN 2
      ELSE 1 END) AS weight
FROM myTable
GROUP BY keyword_name;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ffb70/2) example.

To match the design of your query you have already, you just need to add your having and order by clauses:

```
SELECT keyword_name, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN keyword_name IN ('this', 'that') THEN 3
      WHEN keyword_name IN ('these') THEN 2
      ELSE 1 END) AS weight
FROM myTable
GROUP BY keyword_name
HAVING weight > 2
ORDER BY weight DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a column 'weight' to the keywords table you can use Sum(Weight) and Having Sum(Weight) instead of Count(*)...

Edit:

```
select productid, Sum(weights.weight)
from Keywords
Join (Select 'keyword1' as keyword, 2 as weight
      Union All
      Select 'keyword2' , 5 
      Union All
      Select 'keyword3',  6
) as weights
on Keywords.keyword_name = weights.keyword
group by productid
having Sum(weights.weight) > somevalue
order by weights.weight desc
```